# Reading non-inline CSS style info from Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I know I must be missing something here, but I cannot seem to get this to work.

I have assigned a background color to the body of an html document using the style tags inside the head section of the document, but when I try to read it via JavaScript, I get nothing:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { background-color: #ff0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick='alert(document.body.style.backgroundColor)'>Click Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

.. however, if I assign the style inline, it works:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body style='background-color: #ff0;'>
<a href="#" onclick='alert(document.body.style.backgroundColor)'>Click Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I know I am missing something basic, but my mind is not in the zone today -- can anyone tell me why my first scenario is not working?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048336/cant-access-css-selectors-properties-from-javascript/1048382#1048382

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `style` property of a DOM element refers only to the element's *inline* styles.

Depending on the browser, you can get the actual style of an element using [DOM CSS](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html)

In firefox, for example:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var bg = window.getComputedStyle(body, null).backgroundColor;
```

Or in IE:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var bg = body.currentStyle.backgroundColor;
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you'll want the [`computedStyle`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0440__Style/GetComputedStyle.htm) on the Element as the `style` attribute hasn't been set yet. In IE, you'll need to check the Element's `currentStyle` property, via [something like this](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2007/07/27/18.54.15/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function you can use (without the use of a framework ie) that was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript/324533#324533) by [InsDel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40807/insdel):

```
function getStyle(className) {
    var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules
    for(var x=0;x<classes.length;x++) {
        if(classes[x].selectorText==className) {
                (classes[x].cssText) ? alert(classes[x].cssText) : alert(classes[x].style.cssText);
        }
    }
}
getStyle('.test')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just how css works. There's no straight-forward way to get the computed css attributes of an element within Javascript, that I know of, short of browser specific utilities.