# How come changing styles with document.getElementById() works with styles set inline but not internally?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I set a style inline like this:

```
<div id='myMenu' style='background-color:red'></div>
```

Then in JS call

```
alert("document.getElementById('myMenu')style.backgroundColor");
```

The result alert box would report "red"

However if I set the style internally in the  via a class or id

```
<style type='text/css'>    
.menu {
       background-color:red;
    }
</style>
```

Then the alert reports blank.

Will styles with `.getElementById` only work with inline style? Seems very limiting...

Comment: Setting the style in a style tag should work just fine.  Can you post the actual code you are trying to use? (remember that "." is for class names, and '#' for ID's)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098349/reading-non-inline-css-style-info-from-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the `style` attribute for the element but instead you are setting a `class`.

So...

```
alert(document.getElementById("myMenu").className);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to read the "real" background color, no matter how it was assigned:

```
alert($("#myMenu").css("background-color"));
```

No idea how it's doing it, but I've checked it now and it works. :)

You can download most recent version of jQuery from the official site:
http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery