# Reading CSS value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

This works:

> ```
> <div id="hello" style="width:100%;"></div>
> <script>
> window.onload = function(){
>
> alert(document.getElementById("hello").style.width);
>
> };
> </script>
> ```

This does **not** work:

> ```
> <div id="hello"></div>
> <style>
> div#hello{
>   width:100%;
> }
> </style>
> <script>
> window.onload = function(){
>
> alert(document.getElementById("hello").style.width);
>
> };
> </script>
> ```

- I have also tried properly putting the css style definition in the head tag, didn't work
- I have tried defining a javascript function instead of calling on window.onload , didn't work

strangest thing is, if I set the width using javascript:

> ```
> alert( document.getElementById("hello").style.width );
> document.getElementById("hello").style.width = "25%";
> alert(document.getElementById("hello").style.width );
> ```

It would work. The first alert would show a blank alert, then the second alert will show "25%"

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098349/reading-non-inline-css-style-info-from-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read CSS property of an element using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894577/read-css-property-of-an-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access CSS properties that way that have not been set using Javascript. You need to use `getComputedStyle`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle
On MSIE this works differently.

Comment: Thanks that was informative. I wasn't aware of getComputedStyle and the associated cross-browser problem. Will keep this in mind as a web dev from now on. I chose to use jQuery to overcome this in the end.

Comment: *"...that have not been set using Javascript."* That's incorrect. It's not that they've been set by JavaScript; it's that they're directly applied to the element. That *could* be via JavaScript, or via the `style` attribute in markup.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
window.onload = function(){

var x = document.getElementById("hello");
var y ="";
if (x.currentStyle)
    y = x.currentStyle['width'];
else if (window.getComputedStyle)
    y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue('width');
alert(y);



};
```

It was inspired from something I read [Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html)

Comment: Thanks but this will not work on IE I think. I used jQuery to sort out the cross-browser issue in the end.

Comment: I have tested it in IE 8 and it works. Glad you found a solution using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

In InternetExplorer you can use `.currentStyle` instead of `.style`.  In other browsers, you can use the `getComputedStyle` mechanism.

```
var yourElement = document.getElementById('whatever');
var theStyle = window.getComputedStyle(yourElement);
```

You can then call `.getPropertyValue()` on the returned style object to find the CSS properties you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your css in the head section of the page.

Comment: if you have read my post you would know that is something i have already tried. and no it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think style.width is given a value unless you explicitly define it one. As others have said you can use currentStyle/getComputedStyle to get actual values of CSS items.

If you need JUST the width you can go with element.offsetWidth. If you need the value as a percent you'll have to compare the elements offsetWidth with the parents offsetWidth.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will do it for you

```
$('#hello').mouseover(function({
  alert($(this).width()); 
});
```

Just try it!

Answer (score 0):

Are you adverse to using jQuery?

http://api.jquery.com/width/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($("#hello").width());
});
```