# How to get the rotateY value applied on an HTML element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Here's what I'm trying to figure out:

I have a div with rotateY property applied to it, now i want to get this value using javascript.

`<div class="test" style="transform: rotateY(90deg);"></div>`

I want to target this div and access its rotateY value, the javascript code should return an integer value of 90

Comment: Unless they are written as inline styles (I think), Transforms get translated to a matrix property, under the hood.  To get the matrix of your element, do this: const element = document.querySelector(".test");
const style = getComputedStyle(test);
console.log("style:", style["transform"]);
Then, you have to learn how to decode the matrix object to see what the rotateY would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `transform` style by using `element.style.transform` and then just replace the non numeric characters with empty.

And if you want to have a number typeof result, just wrap it in a `parseInt` with `10` radix

```js
const test = document.querySelector('.test');
const stringResult = test.style.transform.replace( /\D+/g, '');
const numberResult = parseInt(stringResult,10)
console.log(stringResult, typeof stringResult)
console.log(numberResult, typeof numberResult)
```

```html
<div class="test" style="transform: rotateY(90deg);"></div>
```

Comment: I tested this out, and it seems to only work if the style is written inline. Is that true, as far as you know?

Comment: @Maiya that is true in general, and does not have anything in particular to do with the transform property. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1098430/10955263

Comment: Thanks. Was asking b/c the getComputedStyle() for transform gives you the matrix, and it would have been nice if there was a way around that.

Comment: No, for styles set by `CSS` i think the only way is to use `getComputedStyle` . But for inline styles ( like this question ) you can use `style.nameOfProperty`

Comment: @MihaiT Your answer works perfectly when there is only rotateY on the element as inline style, but it doesn't work if I add rotateX as well on the same element. Could you please give me an answer which decodes rotateY from matrix3D? I really appreciate everyone for the time and effort. Thank you all.

Comment: Well i gave the answer for your specific question. If your problem is more complex, please post another question or check the ' duplicate ' question and it's answers

Comment: Sure, thanks @MihaiT

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Example

```js
function getValue() {
 var tr= document.getElementById('test').style.transform.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
 console.log('Rotate: ' + tr + 'deg');
}
```

```html
<div id="test" style="transform: rotateX(90deg);"></div>
<button onclick="getValue()">get</button>
```

Comment: why getElementById ? there is no id in the code of the question. Also, stick to your original answer with `getComputedStyle` . And also, why at click of the button ? Why complicate things ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to return a string with value and unit.

```
var myValue = 90;
document.getElementById('myElement').style.transform = 'rotateY(' + myValue + 'deg)';
```