# How to check element's visibility via javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm interested in a way to check whether an element has display:none style explicility (ie style="display:none"), has a class that has (or inherits) this style, or one of its parents is hidden (and my element inherits this)

Case1:

```
<body><div><span style="display:none;">Some hidden text</span></div>
```

or

```
<body><div style="display:none;"><span>Some hidden text</span></div>
```

Case2:

```
SomeClass {   display:none;   }
<body><div class="SomeClass"><span>Some hidden text</span></div>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are looking for one solution to two different scenarios.

The first scenario is getting the cascaded/computed style for a css property. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048336/cant-access-css-selectors-properties-from-javascript/1048382#1048382) for how to do that.

The second scenario is detecting if any of an element's *parents* are hidden. This requires traversing and is cumbersome and slow.

You can take the solution [outlined here](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/e18b399b36d03f4f) (and employed by jQuery/Sizzle since [1.3.2](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/tags/1.3.2/src/selector.js#L961)), and just read the dimensions of the element:

```
var isVisible = element.offsetWidth > 0 || element.offsetHeight > 0;
```

If it has dimensions then it is visible in the sense that it takes up some rectangular space (however small) in the document. Note that this technique still has [some downsides](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/0334b35ecd875253) for certain elements in certain browsers, but should work in most cases.

Comment: no need to traverse, I only need to check the parent if this will affect the computed style, hence the computer style is enough for me...

thanks for your answer, it helped a lot,
here is the code I finally used:

function IsVisible(elem)
{
    if (elem.currentStyle) // ie only
    {
        return elem.currentStyle["display"] != 'none';
    }
    else
    {
        // jquery way for computing isvisible.
        return (elem.offsetWidth > 0 || elem.offsetHeight > 0);
    }
}

however, I need to do more testing to see whether "||" is enough or do I need to have "&&" instead..

Comment: The jQuery/Sizzle 1.3.2 link is broken, you can now [find it here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.3.2/src/selector.js#L961).

Comment: As of writing the current solution used in jQuery with downsides fixed can be found [here](https://github.com/csnover/jquery/commit/0229b83f7e5bf64edb2888ab349bedcd1a45e7c1#L0L281). Further discussion [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4512).

Comment: This is just a note to say that I've just tested the above solution with IE8 and it seems to be working as expected so the [downsides](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/0334b35ecd875253) mentioned by @Crescent Fresh may no longer apply. I tested IE8 version 8.0.7601.17514.

Comment: "var isVisible" is misleading and should really be "var isDisplayed" in this context, particularly as this answer does not work for "visibility: hidden" where the element still has offset even though it cannot be seen

Comment: @SimonLiescke's link is broken. Folks, this is why you give information, not provide links to information.

Answer (score 6):

This is the quickest and easiest way to determine if an element is visible.

```
function is_visible(e) {return e.offsetWidth > 0 || e.offsetHeight > 0;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Each case will need its own check and you need to know the ID of that element. First, grab the element (just doing this to make the code readable):

```
var MyElementName = document.getElementById("MyElementName");
```

Then do your checks:

**Case 1:**

```
 if (MyElementName.style.display == "none")
```

**Case 2**, looking at the parent, checking FF first:

```
if ((MyElementName.previousSibling.nodeType == 3 )
    && (MyElementName.parentNode.nextSibling.style.display == "none"))
```

then for other browsers:

```
else (MyElementName.parentNode.style.display == "none")
```

**Case 3**, look for an applied css class:

```
if (MyElementName.className = "SomeClass")
```

Answer (score 1):

The above solution caters for this "invisibility" scenario:

```
display:none;
```

but it does not cater for this one:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

In order to include the test for visibility: hidden; the script can be modified as follows...

First, create a cross browser compliant function to get the desired element's computed style:

```
computedStyle = function(vElement) {
  return window.getComputedStyle?
         ?window.getComputedStyle(vElement,null)
         :vElement.currentStyle;                    //IE 8 and less
}
```

Second, create the function to test for visibility

```
isVisible = function(vElement) {
  return !(vElement.offsetWidth == 0 && vElement.offsetHeight == 0)
         && computedStyle(vElement).visibility != "hidden";  
}
```

Finally, simply reference the isVisible function wherever needed as follows:

```
if (isVisible(myElement)) {
  alert('You can see me!');
} else {
  alert('I am invisible ha ha!');
}
```

Just a note that the current isVisible() tests do not cater for a number of "invisibility" scenarios (however the tests could I suppose be enhanced to include these). Here are a few examples:

1. where an element is the same colour as the surrounding colour
2. where an element is visible but physically behind another element eg.  different z-index values

It is also probably worth noting the following regarding the above computedStyle() function:

1. It can of course be used for many other style related purposes besides testing visibility
2. I have opted to ignore :pseudo style testing due to patchy browser support, however with a minor modification to the function this could be included if desired.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
function SomeClass()
{
  if (document.getElementById("MY_DIV_ID").style.display == "none")
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he wants... i think he wants a way to check it if its set by a class or if its done inline, this way will only work if it is done inline