# addClass/removeClass to body when div is in the viewport

Tags: jquery, viewport, addclass

```
<div id="title-box">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
</div>

<div id="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-image"></div>
    <div class="gallery-image"></div> 
    <div class="gallery-image"></div>
    <div class="gallery-image"></div> 
</div>

<div id="text-box">
    <div class="text">
        One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin...
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried various jQuery plugins, but I could not get the desired result. I would like to add a class to the **body** when the "*gallery*" element is visible in the viewport, and to remove a class in the **body** when the "*gallery*" item is no longer visible.

I'm new to jQuery.

Comment: Check  this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1343350/3340702

Comment: You can take a look at this answer for the existing question
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22480938/4731004

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#gallery').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {

        if (visible == true) {
        // element is now visible in the viewport
            $('body').addClass('myclass');
        }
        else{
           $('body').removeClass('myclass');
           alert('removed... pleasecheck body');
        }  
    });
    $('#gallery').trigger('inview');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/M2RzU/247/)

Comment: It seems not to work. I have to link a library? I do not understand what it's 'inview'?

Comment: No... please see my demo

Comment: [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/pietrospagnolo/er7yb6wk/2/) I created a jsfiddle, but does not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the element is out of view port or not. Depending upon the return you can add the class

```js
function isElementOutOfViewport (el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.bottom < 0 || rect.right < 0 || rect.left > window.innerWidth || rect.top > window.innerHeight;
}

alert(isElementOutOfViewport(document.getElementById('bottom')));
```

```css
.bottom {margin-top:100vH}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="title-box">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
</div>

<div id="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-image"></div>
    <div class="gallery-image"></div> 
    <div class="gallery-image"></div>
    <div class="gallery-image"></div> 
</div>

<div id="text-box">
    <div class="text">
        One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom" class="bottom">Not in view port</div>
```