# Passing CSS breakpoints to JS without using getComputedStyle()

Tags: javascript, performance

We are trying to minimize Forced Reflows which can be caused by stuff like `getComputedStyle()`.

Our problem:
Currently we are passing our CSS breakpoints to JavaScript by having an DOM element with the following styling:

```
.breakpoint {
  display: none;

  @media (min-width: $breakpoint-medium) {
    display: block;
  }

  @media (min-width: $breakpoint-large) {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

Then in JS we check the `display` property with `getComputedStyle()` which causes a Forced Reflow.

Do you have an other way of passing the CSS breakpoints to JS without having the Forced Reflow?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not store the break-points in JS variables according CSS files as a constant type? Because you know already how many breakpoints you set. Or you need something else?

Comment: That would be our workaround. We would really like to have a single source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following div to your html:

```html
<body>
   ... your html here
   <div id="breakpoint"></div>
</body>
```

And add this to your SCSS:

```
#breakpoint{
   opacity: 0; //so you do not see it
   width: 1px; //so it works even with a 0 pixel canvas
   position: fixed; // so as not to change your page layout
      @media (max-width: $breakpoint-medium){
         display: none;
      }
   }
}
```

Then in javascript do the following:

```
var getCurrentBreakpoint = function(){
  return document.getElementById('breakpoint').offsetWidth > 0?'desktop':'tablet';
}
//getCurrentBreakpoint() = 'desktop' on desktop
//getCurrentBreakpoint() = 'tablet' on devices smaller than $breakpoint-medium
```

This answer works because the [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)  of an element returns 0 if that element is hidden in all browsers. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1343350/11415228) to an earlier question on 'How to check element's visibility via javascript?'.

**What if I have more than two breakpoints?**

If you have multiple breakpoints just create multiple divs, one for each breakpoint. Then make sure each breakpoint divs is only visible in one breakpoint range.

Answer (score 0):

You could set CSS breakpoints with JavaScript as well, by using the method [insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule).

Here is an example:

```
const css = window.document.styleSheets[0];
css.insertRule(`
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .breakpoint {
      display: none;
    }
  }
`, css.cssRules.length);
```