# Button does not function on the first click

Tags: javascript, html, button, dom-events

```js
function showCheckbox(){  
    var node_list = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
    for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) 
    {  
      if(node_list[i].style.display == 'none') { 
        node_list[i].style.display = 'block';
      } else { node_list[i].style.display = 'none'; }
    }
}
```

```css
input[type=checkbox]{
display:none;
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<input type="button"  value="Εμφάνιση" onclick="showCheckbox()" />
<img src="form-images\trash.png"  onclick="" style="width:21px;height:24px;margin-left:20px; "/>

    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />   
        <label>Ψάρεμα</label>
        <input type="text"  />
    </br>
 <input type="checkbox" class="check" />   
        <label>Γήπεδο</label>
        <input type="text"/>
      </br>
```

When the page loads for first time and I press the button on the first click it does not triggers the onclick function.
If I press it the second time it triggers the event.

Other `<input type="button"/>`  buttons triggers the event on the first click without problem.
Does anyone know what is the problem or did it have the same?

Comment: Post your code and mark up.

Comment: Make sure that the `showCheckbox` function is defined before the HTML. Else, the `input` tag will be asking for a function that doesn't exist(yet).

Comment: i declared all the <script> ... </script> in the head  the error remains
after i put it after the <body> still the error remains .so?

Comment: Does the first click that doesn't work result in any errors in your browser's dev console? (And when you say it doesn't trigger the function, are you certain that the function is not called at all, as compared to it being called but not correctly showing/hiding the checkboxes?)

Comment: inspect element -> console->JS   is blank  so i guess no errors.
On Css  there are many errors but they are at the backgrounds on other classes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I think is happening is that your click handler *is* being called on the first click, but your `if` test isn't working the way you expect. This line:

```
if(node_list[i].style.display == 'none')
```

...is testing whether the element has an *inline* style set. Which it doesn't: it's hidden via a CSS rule that applies to all such inputs. So then your `else` case executes and the `.display` is set to `'none'`. Then on the *next* click, the `if` works as expected and changes `.display` to `'block'`.

**You can see this for yourself if you actually debug your function a little** to see if it is getting called and test the value of that `.display` property - as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/uLjxp3ha/ (note: I don't recommend `alert()`s for debugging).

Checking the current visibility as set by stylesheet rules is a bit trickier because it doesn't work consistently across browsers. You may need to test for existence of `.currentStyle` and [`.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) to allow for whichever one the current browser might support. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1048382/615754) to another question for more information about that.

But in your case given that you *know* the checkboxes are hidden to begin with you can simply invert your if/else:

```
  if(node_list[i].style.display == 'block') { 
    node_list[i].style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    node_list[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
```

The `.display` will not be `'block'` to start with, so the else will be executed and the elements will be displayed.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uLjxp3ha/1/

Comment: You are Right.That was a really weird error.
Thanks.
Did my comment on Css helped you to find this?

Comment: No, I didn't see that comment until after putting the answer up.

Comment: haha ok you helped me to use the console...i was thinking it was useless to check CSS from console if JS has not errors

Comment: Can you explain why `node_list[i].style.display` refers to inline style set? I used Google Dev Tools in the browser and first (no clicks) it shows something `element = {}`. After the first click, the property is saved/copied inside the `element`, and only after that does the programmed change occurs on the second click. Is there a difference between "style" and "element"? This has me confused.

Comment: @ChinmayGhule - `node_list[i]` refers to the element. The `node_list[i].style.display` property refers to the inline `display` style on that element if that inline style has been set.

Comment: @nnnnnnn I didn't know that you can only change inline styles like this, but for external styles we have to use `getComputedStyle()`. Should we just always use `getComputedStyle()` since then it wouldn't matter whether the element has an inline style or an external one?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is brittle, easy to break. I suggest you to create a clear separation of concerns between css and javascript.

Also, your use of `check` class was twofold: select elements and hide them. That are two things better managed not coupled to each other.

Changing an element class could be as easy as:

```
node_list[i].classList.toggle('check-hidden');
```

You'll need to create a new css class for the actually hidden checkboxes.

```js
function showCheckbox(){  
    var node_list = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
    for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) 
    {  
        node_list[i].classList.toggle('check-hidden');
    }
}
```

```css
.check {
    position:relative;
}

.check-hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button"  value="Εμφάνιση" onclick="showCheckbox()" />
<img src="form-images\trash.png"  onclick="" style="width:21px;height:24px;margin-left:20px; "/>

    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />   
        <label>Ψάρεμα</label>
        <input type="text"  />
    </br>
 <input type="checkbox" class="check" />   
        <label>Γήπεδο</label>
        <input type="text"/>
      </br>
```

Comment: I do not understand  what you mean "brittle, easy to break."I am obligated to use only JS no Jquery 
What do you mean by "brittle, easy to break."?

Comment: By brittle I mean that it is fragile at this point. Inverting conditions could make it work, but won't make your code more robust. A change on css would make it break again.

Comment: And software should have only a single reason to break. Any change unrelated to the behaviour you have implemented shouldn't break that behaviour. It's all about code quality.

Comment: Ah, glad to see that you are bound to pure JS. My snippet is pure JS.

Comment: Why to break again?What are you thinking?
Speak briefly just for informative purposes.

Comment: @MilsZ for instance, your initial visibility configuration was based on CSS, and HTML element inheriting from its class. Then on-click you switched over to redefine element style (its own, not its class) on JS. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: So you mean it is n't 100% right to use this approach and change temporary the Css style because the Basic class is still the same.
I find on this lines some truth but my experience on JS/Css is only 1 month (university now).I learn.

Comment: @MilsZ yes, but don't worry, you'll get it as you practice and try to solve problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

reason is pretty simple:
when you get a "style" property, it represents inline styles of that element. On fist click there is no inline style for "display", 
so else fork fires and sets inline style for "display" to "none"

What you may do is next

1. Use computed style

   window.getComputedStyle(node_list[i]).display == "none"
2. Or switch "if" statement to

   if(node_list[i].style.display == 'block')
       node_list[i].style.display = 'none';
   else node_list[i].style.display = 'block';

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle

Comment: Right.i didn't knew the "inline thing".Thank you too.

Answer (score 0):

The style.display property is not present the first time you do the loop, you could change the code as follows:

```
    function showCheckbox(){
    var node_list = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
    for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++)
    {
        if(node_list[i].style.display !== 'none' || !node_list[i].style.display) {
            node_list[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else { node_list[i].style.display = 'none'; }
    }
}
```

A better solution might be (if you can use jQuery)

```
    function showCheckbox(){

    $( "input.check" ).each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'none'){
            $(this).css('display','block')
        } else {
            $(this).css('display','none')
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing display: none in your css file, write it inline in your html document so it'd be more like:

```
<input style="display: none" type="checkbox" class="check" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this and try I will work because if statement first check the code and then runs

```
for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) 
    {  
      if(node_list[i].style.display == 'block') { 
        node_list[i].style.display = 'none';
      } else { node_list[i].style.display = 'block'; }
    }
```