# d3js selectAll elements by its CSS style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, filter

Is there a way to select all `circle` with style `visibility===visible`?  Something like this:
`svg.selectAll("circle").filter(function(d) { return this.style.visibility === 'visible'; })`

Answer (score -1):

You can use d3.selectAll to select all circle svgs (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_selectAll).

This is going to return a 2 dimensional array. It's essentially an array containing arrays of what you selected. Assuming you have 25 circles:

```
circs = d3.selectAll("circle") // here circs may be [Array[25]]
circs = circs[0] //now circs is an array of circles
```

Now all you need to do is filter based on the computed style for that element. [Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048336/cant-access-css-selectors-properties-from-javascript/1048382#1048382) for how you'd do that :)